# Getting <Select> defaultValue to set from a state. React MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've been working on this one bug for a couple of days and cannot find anything that will fix it.

What I'm attempting to do is populate the pre-selected value that comes from the local storage and connects with fetch request data. The select request data populates as the menu options and the default select should be saved locally so when the user refreshed or leaves the comes back, their league is still selected.

I'm getting the data to send in console.log() when it renders, but it will not populate the `<Select default={currentLeague}>`.

Here's my code in question:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from  "react";

import { 
AppBar, Toolbar, Tabs, Tab, Button, Box, Menu, MenuItem, Divider, Typography, Grid, Select, FormControl, } from '@mui/material';

export default function NavBar(props){
    const [leagues, setLeagues] = useState([]);
    const [currentLeague, setCurrentLeague] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        getLeagues();
        setCurrentLeague(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentLeague')));
     }, []);

    const getLeagues = () => {
        fetch('/draft/get-user-leagues')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setLeagues(data)
            })
    }

    function handleLeagueChange(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('currentLeague', JSON.stringify(e.target.value));
    }   

    function leagueDropdown(leagues) {
        if (leagues.length === 0) {
            return (<Button
                    component={Link}
                    to='/create-league'
                    >
                        Create New League <AddCircleIcon sx={{marginLeft:'10px'}}/>
                    </Button>
            )
        } else {
        console.log("current League: " + currentLeague.name);
        console.log(currentLeague)
        return (
            <Select
                defaultValue={currentLeague}
                onChange={handleLeagueChange}
            >
                {leagues.map((league, index) => {
                    return <MenuItem 
                                value={league}
                            > 
                                {league.name}
                            </MenuItem>
                })}
            </Select>
        )
    }

    return (
    <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
            <FormControl>
                {leagueDropdown(leagues)}
            </FormControl>
        </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
    )
}
```

I can get the defaultValue to populate if I manually put in 'leagues[1]' but I cannot populate it using currentLeague.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Edit to add the response:

```
    [
  {
    "name": "TestLeague2",
    "owner": "0e31ac27-8978-49cb-81e0-fa6259bdad2b",
    "year": 2022,
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "TestLeague2",
    "owner": "0e31ac27-8978-49cb-81e0-fa6259bdad2b",
    "year": 2022,
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "TestLeague2",
    "owner": "0e31ac27-8978-49cb-81e0-fa6259bdad2b",
    "year": 2022,
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "TestLeague55",
    "owner": "0e31ac27-8978-49cb-81e0-fa6259bdad2b",
    "year": 2022,
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "TestLeague55",
    "owner": "0e31ac27-8978-49cb-81e0-fa6259bdad2b",
    "year": 2022,
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Jacob's League",
    "owner": "0e31ac27-8978-49cb-81e0-fa6259bdad2b",
    "year": 2022,
    "id": 6
  },
  {
    "name": "test234",
    "owner": "0e31ac27-8978-49cb-81e0-fa6259bdad2b",
    "year": 2022,
    "id": 7
  },
  {
    "name": "teasdf",
    "owner": "0e31ac27-8978-49cb-81e0-fa6259bdad2b",
    "year": 2022,
    "id": 8
  },
  {
    "name": "teasdf",
    "owner": "0e31ac27-8978-49cb-81e0-fa6259bdad2b",
    "year": 2022,
    "id": 9
  },
  {
    "name": "teasdf",
    "owner": "0e31ac27-8978-49cb-81e0-fa6259bdad2b",
    "year": 2022,
    "id": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "please1",
    "owner": "0e31ac27-8978-49cb-81e0-fa6259bdad2b",
    "year": 2022,
    "id": 11
  }
]
```

Comment: Just use the `value` prop instead of `defaultValue` since you've a fully controlled input component. You *should* be seeing some React warnings in the console regarding trying to change the `defaultValue` prop value.

Comment: value is originally where I had started, I just tried changing it back to value with no luck. But, I am not seeing any react warning regarding defaultValue, any ideas on why that might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `currentLeague` state and actually fully control the select input. Use the `value` prop instead of the `defaultValue` prop that you are trying to change *after* the initial render.

You can initialize the `currentLeague` state directly from localStorage. Enqueue normal React state updates in the `onChange` handler and use an `useEffect` hook to persist the state changes to localStorage.

You can't use object for the select input's option values, so I suggest using the `league.id` property as the select value.

Example:

```
export default function NavBar(props){
  const [leagues, setLeagues] = useState([]);
  const [currentLeague, setCurrentLeague] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentLeague')) || ''
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    getLeagues();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('currentLeague', JSON.stringify(currentLeague));
  }, [currentLeague]);

  const getLeagues = () => {
    fetch('/draft/get-user-leagues')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setLeagues(data)
      });
  };

  function handleLeagueChange(e) {
    setCurrentLeague(e.target.value);
  }   

  function leagueDropdown(leagues) {
    if (leagues.length === 0) {
      return (
        <Button component={Link} to='/create-league'>
          Create New League <AddCircleIcon sx={{marginLeft:'10px'}}/>
        </Button>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <Select
          value={currentLeague}
          onChange={handleLeagueChange}
        >
          {leagues.map((league, index) => (
            <MenuItem key={league.id} value={league.id}> 
              {league.name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <AppBar>
      <Toolbar>
        <FormControl>
          {leagueDropdown(leagues)}
        </FormControl>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit getting-select-defaultvalue-to-set-from-a-state-react-mui]

Comment: That still did not work for me. My next thought is that maybe the data for currentLeague is in the wrong format, but after console.log() of both currentLeague and league[0] they're objects with the same format.

Comment: @JacobSimerly That is likely correct. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that reproduces the issue? Please mock the `'/draft/get-user-leagues'` API response.

Comment: The embedded link isn't working, try this one: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-nightingale-8hmuqf?file=/src/App.js